# Despite having powered USB Hub, Raspberry Pi 2+ doesn't detect Seagate 1TB HDD anymore

Tags: power-supply, hard-drive

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi 2+ as an always on torrent box. I had it set up one time and it was working, but then when I turned it off and on again it froze on start up. After flashing the card and retrying a couple of times, now the raspberry pi won't even detect the HDD on startup after flashing. The HDD is using a powered USB hub, and my raspberry pi 3+ does start the hdd when I connect it to it using the hub. Any ideas why my 2+ won't start the hdd but my 3+ does?

Thanks very much

Comment: "I turned it off and on again" - did you just turn off or `poweroff`?

Comment: It was switched off from the plug socket. Which I understand isn't great, but I don't get  why the hdd currently boots no problem for my pi 3 but not my pi 2.  I just did a fresh os install (raspian) on the pi 2 and I won't detect the hdd

Comment: Post output of `lsusb` and `ls /dev/sd*'

Comment: I just plugged in the hard after taking it out of the pi 3 and it just worked this tine. The light went on straight away on the drive. Can see the drive listed on lsusb now. 

Any idea why it mightn't have booted before? I've been going crazy over this. It's almost worse that it's seemingly fixed itself without me doing anything.

Comment: It sounds like you are short on power. Is the drive motor driven of the older style or new style there is a difference in current. Extra current availability does not hurt most designs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a power meter USB. This will show you how much power is required to power it. Also try using a USB port on the actual pi

Comment: Suggestion - You could improve your answer by saying why this would work.  It is obvious to me, but maybe not to others.  And that's why I cant upvote it as is.